# .net Interrop Outlook ItemChangeEvent fires several times

Tags: .net, outlook, ms-office, office-pia

I'm using interrop to handle changing events in outlook so when a calandar item is chaged i can display a message.The problem is that it fire the event  3 times :s.

here is the code :

```
Private Sub mCalendarItems_ItemChangeEvent(ByVal Item As NetOffice.COMObject) Handles                     mCalendarItems.ItemChangeEvent
           Dim i As outlook.AppointmentItem = Nothing
           i = DirectCast(Item, outlook.AppointmentItem) 
        If i IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Vous venez de modifier la tâche " & i.Subject)
            Application.DoEvents()
         End If
    i = Nothing End Sub
```

Any help ?

Comment: Event fires 3 times for me as well, only saving once, event is also only registered once.

Answer (score 0):

I gad the same problem, but found out it had nothing to do with the event handler. The reason for the multiple events were, that I have HotMail Connector installed and this will modify the Item two times when synchronizing.